# Посчитать или подсчитать?

Tags: орфография

Писал предыдущий вопрос и задумался: как правильно — "поДсчитать" или "посчитать"? Или тут разные значения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без контекста сказать трудно, что имелось в виду. 
Значения не то чтобы разные но, так скажем, различимые.

ПОСЧИТАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; посчитанный; -тан, -а, -о; св. (нсв. считать).
1. (кого-что). Произвести подсчёт; сосчитать. П. деньги. П. людей в отряде. П. до десяти. П. петли (при вязании). П. пульс  
(определить частоту ударов сердца). Сколько будет десять плюс три, посчитал?
2. чем или каким, с инф., также с придат. дополнит. Разг.
Составить какое-л. мнение по поводу чего-л.; прийти к какому-л. мнению, решению, заключению. П. необходимым сделать что-л. П. себя обязанным кому-л. Посчитал, что можно уйти. // кого каким, кем-чем и за кого-что.
Принять, счесть за кого-, что-л. П. кого-л. дураком. П. за сумасшедшего кого-л.
3. и без дополн. Некоторое время считать. П. на компьютере.

//-------------------------

ПОДСЧИТАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; подсчитанный; -тан, -а, -о; св. кого-что или с придат. дополнит.
Считая, подвести итог, установить наличность, количество чего-л. П. выигрыш. П. расходы. П., во что обойдётся Олимпиада. ◊ Бабки подсчитать.
Подвести итог, результат, баланс и т.п. < Подсчитывать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Подсчитываться, -ается; страд. Подсчитывание, -я; ср. Ежедневные п. денежной кассы.

В первом значении ПОСЧИТАТЬ совпадает или почти совпадает с ПОДСЧИТАТЬ. Два других - уникальны.

В "совпадающем" значении лучше употребить тот вариант, который ближе по стилю. "Подсчитать" хорошо согласуется с подсчетом некоего итога, результата. В остальных случаях, вернее будет "посчитать". Но это не абсолют, можно и отойти от этого совета.